# Sort array of numbers with arithmetic operators vs comparison operators

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting, comparison-operators

In Javascript there's two solutions to write the `sort()` function to sort an array of numbers in ascending order.

```
var numbers = [2, 10, 2, 6, 4];
// first solution
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b); // [2, 2, 4, 6, 10]

// second solution
numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b); // [2, 2, 4, 6, 10]
```

Which one is better or faster to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sort` callback must return a value <0, 0 or >0, *not a boolean*. Using `>` is simply *incorrect*. How it will affect the performance or correctness of the sorting algorithm is implementation dependent (i.e. different engines may show different results).

Comment: But using > still gives me the wanted result. How is it incorrect?

Comment: You're declaring all cases where `a < b` as "equal". Your comparison function is *incoherent*, i.e. will give incoherent results for values `1,2` ("equal") and `2,1` ("greater"). That may or may not throw off the sorting algorithm and cause it to do additional iterations that a *correct* answer would have prevented.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, I have done a [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/sorting-numbers-with-operators/1) snippet, the boolean operator seems to be faster.

PD: Using Google Chrome Versión 59.0.3071.115 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Answer (score -1):

In C, we'd always favour `a - b` over `a > b` since the latter can cause a pipeline dump due to a failure in the branch predictor.

In Javascript though, you don't micro-optimise to that level. Write what's clearest. Better still, use the out-of-the box solution.